# Mustache - How to detect array is not empty?

Tags: arrays, logic, mustache

I want to implement the following logic with Mustache:

```
{{#if users.length > 0}}
    <ul>
        {{#users}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
{{/if}}

// eg. data = { users: ['Tom', 'Jerry'] }
```

Should I modify the `users` structure to meet the need? For example:

```
{{#hasUsers}}
    <ul>
        {{#users}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
{{/hasUsers}}

// eg. data = { hasUsers: true, users: ['Tom', 'Jerry'] }
```

Comment: Yes, I believe you are going to have to modify the data like you've done with `hasUsers`. Another option is using the more robust [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) which handles this exact case on their homepage.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Sorry, this may be too late. But I had similar requirement and found a better way to do this:

```
{{#users.length}}
    <ul>
        {{#users}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
{{/users.length}}
{{^users.length}}
    <p>No Users</p>
{{/users.length}}
```

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/eSvdb/

Comment: Please note though, this is not a standard mustache function. It varies depending on Mustache implementation.

Comment: Never too late on SO :)

Comment: I can confirm, as @corgrath said, that this is implementation-dependant: it isn't working with samskivert's Java Mustache library.

Comment: #users.length - check if array is/or not null

Comment: Try `{{#users.size}}` with the Java implementation.

Comment: `{{#users.size}}` works also for C# (length doesn't)

Answer (score 48):

Using {{#users.length}} works great if you want the inner statement to repeat for every element of the array, but if you only want a statement to only run **once**, you can use:

```
{{#users.0}}
...
{{/users.0}}
{{^users.0}}
...
{{/users.0}}
```

Comment: this way also works well with php since arrays doesn't have length property.

Comment: Will fail if `users` is an array of arrays, though.

Comment: it works! but it's not documented in the official mustache doc.

Comment: Great idea I was having just this problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) for Python. Since `{{#users.length}}` is implementation-dependent as described in previous answers, and doesn't work for me in Chevron, I return an object in my code which only contains the list if the list is non-empty. Presumably this technique would work for other languages too.

```py
users = ["user1", "user2", "userN"]
user_obj = {"user_list": users} if len(users) > 0 else {}
template = """
{{#users}}
<ul>
    {{#user_list}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/user_list}}
</ul>
{{/users}}
"""

chevron.render(template, {"users": user_obj})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) for Python, you can test for the existence of the first array element to test whether the array is non-empty:

```html
{{#users.0}}
    <ul>
        {{#users}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
{{/users.0}}
```