# Mustache Conditions and Loops

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mustache

Here are the resources:

**JSON**

```
{
  "badges":{
    "unlocked": [
      {"name": "Win 1"},
      {"name": "Win 2"},
      {"name": "Win 3"}
    ],
    "locked":[
      {"name": "Lose 1"},
      {"name": "Lose 2"},
      {"name": "Lose 3"}
    ]
  }
}
```

**Algorithm**

```
{{ if_has_badges }}
<div class="badges">
  <h1>Badges</h1>

  {{ if_has_badges_unlocked }}
    <div class="badges-unlocked">
      <h2>Unlocked!</h2>
      {{ loop_badges_unlocked }}
      <a href="#" class="badge">
        <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
      </a>
      {{ end_loop_badges_unlocked }}
    </div>
  {{ end_if_has_badges_unlocked }}

  {{ if_has_badges_locked }}
    <div class="badges-locked">
      <h2>Locked!</h2>
      {{ loop_badges_locked }}
      <a href="#" class="badge">
        <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
      </a>
      {{ end_loop_badges_locked }}
    </div>
  {{ end_if_has_badges_locked }}

</div>
{{ end_if_has_badges }}
```

How I can write this algorithm to work with Mustache compiler?

I need to do this to work with two sides, first is the RubyOnRails application and the second is the client-side (JavaScript).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem.

### Using selections and inverted selections

Here is an example from the mustache documentation:

```
{
  "repos": []
}
```

Template:

```
{{#repos}}<b>{{name}}</b>{{/repos}}
{{^repos}}No repos :({{/repos}}
```

Output:

```
No repos :(
```

As you see the inverted selections let me do conditional logic. In your case it would look something like:

Json:

```
var viewModel = {
    badges:[]//badges here
}
viewModel.anyBadges = badges.length >0;
```

Mustache:

```
    <div class="badges-unlocked">
   {{#anyBadges}}
      <h2>Unlocked!</h2>
   {{/anyBadges}}
   {{#badges_unlocked}}
      <a href="#" class="badge">
        <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
      </a>
   {{/badges_unlocked}}
```

### Don't do logic in logic-less templating

This is what I would do. If you have conditional logic in your Mustache templates I think you're doing it wrong. You can either use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) instead which is much more advanced in this regard or move your logic someplace else (to your javascript).

Please see the [Mustache readme](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Answer (score 5):

The best answer (for both Ruby and JavaScript) is to encapsulate your logic (the `if_has_badges` type questions) into a View class.

You can actually fake it for the little bit of logic you need in both Ruby and JavaScript by using the array `length` property:

```
{{# badges.length }}
<div class="badges">
  <h1>Badges</h1>

  {{# badges.unlocked.length }}
    <div class="badges-unlocked">
      <h2>Unlocked!</h2>
      {{# badges.unlocked }}
      <a href="#" class="badge">
        <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
      </a>
      {{/ badges.unlocked }}
    </div>
  {{/ badges.unlocked.length }}

  {{# badges.locked.length }}
    <div class="badges-locked">
      <h2>Locked!</h2>
      {{# badges.locked }}
      <a href="#" class="badge">
        <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
      </a>
      {{/ badges.locked }}
    </div>
  {{# badges.locked.length }}

</div>
{{/ badges.length }}
```

But that's a bit of a dirty way of doing it...

Comment: Dirty but effective :) similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17897136/188926