# How can I structure my MustacheJS template to add dynamic classes based on the values from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, mustache

**OBJECTIVE**
To build an app that allows the user to search for locations.

**CURRENT STATE**
At the moment the locations listed are few, so they are just all presented when landing on the "dealers" page.

**BACKGROUND**
Previously there were only about 50 showrooms carrying a product we sell, so a static HTML page was fine. 
 
[image: example of code]
And displays as 
[image: displays as]

But the page size grew to about 1500 lines of code after doing this. We have gotten more and need a scalable solution so that we can add many more dealers fast. In other projects, I have previously used MustacheJS and to load in values from a JSON file. I know the ideally this will be an AJAX application. Perhaps I might be better off with database here?

Below is what I have in mind so far, and it "works" up to a certain point, but seems not to be anywhere near the most sustainable solution that can be efficiently scaled.

**HTML**

```
<a id="{{state}}"></a>
      <div>
        <h4>{{dealer}} : {{city}}, {{state}} {{l_type}}</h4>
        <div class="{{icon_class}}">
          <ul>
            <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></li>
            <li><i class="icon-phone"></i></li>
            <li><i class="icon-print"></i></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  

        <div class="listingInfo">
          <p>{{street}} <br>{{suite}}<br>
            {{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}}<br>
            Phone: {{phone}}<br>
            {{toll_free}}<br>
            {{fax}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
<hr>
```

**JSON**

```
{ "dealers" : [
  { 
    "dealer":"Benco Dental",
    "City":"Denver",
    "state":"CO",
    "zip":"80112",
    "l_type":"Showroom",
    "icon_class":"listingIcons_3la",
    "phone":"(303) 790-1421",
    "toll_free":null,
    "fax":"(303) 790-1421"
    },
    {
    "dealer":"Burkhardt Dental Supply",
    "City":"Portland",
    "state":"OR",
    "zip":"97220",
    "l_type":"Showroom",
    "icon_class":"listingIcons",
    "phone":" (503) 252-9777",
    "toll_free":"(800) 367-3030",
    "fax":"(866) 408-3488"  
  }
]}
```

**CHALLENGES**

- The CSS class wrapping the `ul` will vary based on how many fields there are. In this case there are 3, so the class is "listingIcons_3la"
- The "toll free" number section should only show up if in fact, there is a toll free number.
- the fax number should only show up if there is a value for a fax number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditionals, you can use

```
{{#toll_free}}
  {{toll_free}}
{{/toll_free}}
```

Which will only display the content in between the tags if it is not `null`, `undefined`, or `false`. Otherwise, it will completely ignore that content.

For the listing icons class, you should simplify your html to use the `li` for both the icon and the text. That way you can surround the whole thing in conditionals from Mustache and avoid having to deal with using such classes entirely. An example would be:

```
{{#toll_free}}
  <li><i class="icon-phone"></i>{{toll_free}}</li>
{{/toll_free}}
```

Using CSS, you can achieve the same look you have now with some padding. I made a fiddle to show this and the working template code, based roughly on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/NGwge/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out mustache conditionals (with a poc) at http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/easy-html-templates-with-mustache/sections-conditional.html. That will take care of 2 and 3

With the ".length" piece from [Mustache Conditions and Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041930/mustache-conditions-and-loops), you should be able to accomplish 1

1. The CSS class wrapping the ul will vary based on how many fields
   there are. In this case there are 3, so the class is
   "listingIcons_3la"
2. The "toll free" number section should only show up if in fact, there
   is a toll free number.
3. the fax number should only show up if there is a value for a fax
   number.